# How to install Mailchimp in magento 2.4.5

Tags: composer, magento2.4.5, mailchimp

I am trying to install MailChimp in the following way but unfortunately, it did not work for me.

composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2:103.4.53

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try only:

```
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2
```

It works with 2.4.5.

You can ignore the platform check by:

```
 composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore php versions to install this extension as you have some extensions which are not compatible with your current Magento versions.

So to ignore those compatibility check you need to user `--ignore-platform-reqs` after the composer command to install extension.

```
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

You can also face this problem during installation of other extensions or during `composer install` and `composer update` commands. For that you have to use this `--ignore-platform-reqs` after the command